# TCL - Classes or dictionaries?

Tags: class, dictionary, oop, tcl

I would like to store data that transverse several levels of hierarchy.

For example:

A data structure that stores cars may store the colour, age and other aspects of each vehicle.

The question is: does it make more sense to use dictionaries or OOP for this problem? And how do I print such a structure into a table format?

Please imagine that I don't know "*a priori*" the number of levels (depth) of the data structure.
Please check the picture attached.

Cheers,

Pedro[image: Data Structure example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for setting/retrieving key/value pairs, I also recommend a nested dictionary instead of OOP.

```
set cars {
    Porsche {
        color  black
        engine 3.2L
        fuel   petrol
    }

    Jeep {
        color  blue
        engine 1.6L
        fuel   diesel
    }
    Ferrari {
        color  red
        engine 4.8L
        fuel   petrol
    }
}


# Get a value
set Porsche [dict get $cars Porsche]
dict get $Porsche color
  --> black

# Get a value with nested keys
dict get $cars Ferrari color
  --> red

# Change a value with nested keys
dict set cars Jeep color yellow
```

For a depth with two nested keys, this will make a table.
Any deeper nested keys will be printed in $value, but in a single row.

```
dict for {car_name car_dict} $cars {
    dict for {key value} $car_dict {
        puts [format "%-15s %-15s %s" $car_name $key $value]
    }
}
```

There are options to pretty print a dict (for example, https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/pdict%3A+Pretty+print+a+dict)

You might want to reverse the dictionary to make the table how you want it.

```
set reverse_dict [dict create]
dict for {car_name car_dict} $cars {
    dict for {key value} $car_dict {
        dict set reverse_dict $key $car_name $value
    }
}

set keys [dict keys $reverse_dict]                           
set number_of_columns [expr {[llength $keys] + 1}]
set fmt [lrepeat $number_of_columns "%-15s"]
puts [format $fmt Car {*}$keys]
puts [format $fmt {*}[lrepeat $number_of_columns "------------"]]
foreach car [dict keys $cars] {
    set values [lmap k $keys {dict get $cars $car $k}]
    puts [format $fmt $car {*}$values]
}
```

There are probably many solutions.

Comment: Thanks Chris.
But how do I print in the format below?

car            |  Color     | Engine    |    Fuel <ENTER>
Porsche   | Black      |   3.2l.       | Petrol <ENTER>
Jeep       | Blue          |   1.6l       | Diesel <ENTER>

Sorry but I don't know how to format this into a table....

Comment: I added to my answer with an example for that tabl.e

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to put behaviour with each node in that tree (e.g., will each car have a `turnOnEngine` method?) then it's probably easier to use a nested set of dictionaries. Tcl's classes only really make sense once you start adding significant behaviours, as they have a lot more overhead (a whole namespace each!) than a simple `dict` has.

As long as the overall structure is regular, with lots of repeated patterns (as your diagram seems too show), it's not too important to get “I know what I am” information stored in each node.

Comment: I've no idea how to print as a table. Or maybe too many ideas; that's just totally open ended in my mind.

Comment: The idea of using classes is because each object could have as methods, for example: add a new car, print, remove a car, etc .
Using dictionaries I've done it the following way:
My dictionary is 

"Porsche {Color Black Engine 3.2l Petrol} Jeep {Color Blue Engine 1.6ll Fuel Diesel} Ferrari {Color Red Engine 4.8l Fuel Petrol}"

As I know the hierarchy I can eventually do:
```dict for {k1 v1} $b {lappend mylst "$k1 $v1"}
dict for {k2 v2} $v1 {lappend mylst "$k2 $v2"}```
But, what if I don't know the number of levels of the hierarchy?
Cheers,
Pedro